# Grease Pencil to move boundaries

Tags: grease-pencil

I have original grayscale image and pink boundaries. The goal is to vectorize the boundaries and move with them. As it is shown on the image below.
[image]

What are the possibilities? I found that there is a Grease pencil. I can trace image to grease pencil. It creates a new object from boundaries. There I can move with them. But what next? How can I get grease pencil boundaries back to image? I need to process them in Python. Do you have any ideas?
[image]
Thanks for you advices.